# Is it possible in C++ to transfer a buffer of a different type between std::vector objects of incompatible types

Tags: c++, containers

I have two vectors `std::vector<Type1>` and `std::vector<Type2>` with two different incompatible types `Type1` and `Type2` of related sizes (for example, `sizeof(Type1)==2*sizeof(Type2)`).

I would like to perform a `swap()` operation, just like what `std::vector::swap()`does but between vectors with incompatible types.

The reason: performance. I don't want to spend time copying data just because types are nominally different when I know that they are de-facto compatible as arrays.

What is the nicest way in C++ to do this?

(Please don't tell me that I need to somehow reconcile `Type1` and `Type2` into one type, I really can't do this for reasons outside of the scope of this question.)

Sample:

```
  std::vector<Type1> vec1 = getVec1(); // this returns the vector of Type1
  std::vector<Type2> *vec2 = needThisFunctionThatCreatesVec2WithTheSameBuffer(&vec1); // ????? looking for 
  consumeVec2(vec2); // this consumes vec2
```

Comment: could you provide a sample of what you'd like to do? its not clear to me whether you're just trying to avoid allocations or if you're just wanting to manipulate the buffer in a non-standard way.

Comment: You seem confident ... are you confident enough that you would consider using memcpy().    (using addresses starting at each element[0]). i.e. each element is POD

Comment: @kmdreko Added a sample

Comment: @2785528 I am confident these are simple types.

Comment: You can try `memcpy` or `reinterpret_cast` and it may work for a given setup, but subverting the c++ type system is bound to end up badly.

Comment: do you care about the contents of `vec1` ?

Comment: @JenniferM.: "*when I know that they are de-facto compatible as arrays*" But they're *not* "de-facto compatible as arrays". Not if the sizes are different.

Comment: @PaulEvans I don't want to use memcpy, it takes time. I literally want buffers to swap between them. I guess C++ can't really do this, though.

Comment: @JenniferM. You `swap` buffers by reassigning pointers, if they're type incompatible  you force it with `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: I posted an answer but deleted it. It was more like a half-kidding answer anyway. Even if you swap with a reinterpret_cast, when the vector gets destroyed, you're deleting the wrong type and the wrong size. You're looking at heap corruption.

Comment: I think we very likely have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. Assuming there was such a magic function, what are you actually hoping this will enable you to do and why do you think that is the way it should be done?

Comment: An actual [mcve], not pseudo code.

Comment: I don't think this question makes any sense.  taking the example of type1=int and type2=float, then what are you expecting vec2 to actually contain?  If the types aren't compatible, then they're not compatible.  If they are compatible, but you've not provided a way to convert them, then just pass vec1 around, and provide an implicit conversion operator as required.

Take a few steps backwards - what problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: @UKMonkey I believe he refers to a case like `Type1=pair<int,int>` and `Type2=int`

Comment: @ALX23z if that was the case, which the question doesn't make clear which is why I asked and down voted, then what he wants is to make his own iterator that returns each item in each pair ... and he can specialise it for the container of std::pair<X, X>.  However I would strongly suggest against assuming anything here - if it's not clear, then what's the point of answering a question that doesn't help anyone?

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector` doesn't support such a feature.

I'd recommend a mildly dirty workaround by creating an artificial `std::span<Type2>` and let the function `ConsumeVec2` consume the `span` instead of the `vector`.

I know `std::span` is not out yet in the standard, but it isn't hard to write a quick replacement with the functionality you need (assuming you need only simple things), or you can use `boost::span` (sry, haven't tested it hope somebody can verify it).

Fundamentally the class `span` is a viewer - it is not a container but a reference to an existing one - it holds `begin` and `end` pointers, and allows vector functionality except changing size of the original vector and/or reallocating data.

You'll need to change interface of the `ConsumeVec2` function so it will accept `span`. And it won't work if the function modifies the size of the vector. So I am not fully certain if it solves your problem.